# How to Hotspot Google Maps Business View?

Tags: google-maps, virtual, google-street-view

How to create a hotspot in a virtual tour Google Maps Business View? 
I would also like to place a navigation menu to quickly navigate through a virtual tour Google Maps Business View ...

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score -2):

check out [www.tourdash.com](http://www.tourdash.com) this is the Google approved application for hotspots and navigation menu for Google Business View. You can only get a licence through a Google Trusted Photographer though. There are some other solutions that have been developed as well, you should be able to Google them!